# TableRow fill remaining space

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a layout like the following:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".SettingsActivity" >

<TableRow
    ...
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    ...
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Temperature:" />

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</TableRow>
```

In the third `TableRow` the `TextView` and the `SeekBar` share the space equally. I want the `TextView` to be only as wide is the text inside it, and the `SeekBar` should fill the rest of the space. I have tried fiddling with gravity, width, and weights. What is the best way to get this behavior?

Comment: Change the weights of  row in java depending on lenghth of edittext in event of keypress

Comment: It isn't an EditText. It's an uneditable text box.

Comment: Use `android:stretchColumns="1"` on the `TableLayout`. This would however make all the views from the second column take as much space as needed. If you don't want this then `TableLayout` is not the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. I switched to a RelativeLayout.